# Request failed for pin 180 on live USB boot

Tags: boot, dell, live-usb, inspiron

I am helping a friend install Kubuntu 19.10 on his new [Dell Inspiron 14 7490](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-7490-laptop/overview) laptop.

When we select the USB drive from the boot menu (to boot into live USB), we get the following error:

```
cannonlake-pinctrl INT34BB:00: request() failed for pin 180
cannonlake-pinctrl INT34BB:00: pin-180 (INT34BB:00:431) status -16
```

[image: Picture of the error]

The laptop is brand new, here are the exact steps we followed:

1. Download `kubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso` from [the official website](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/). We checked that the checksums are OK.
2. Create a bootable USB drive using Rufus. We set the partition scheme to `MBR`, target system to `BIOS or UEFI` and file system to `FAT32`.
3. Reboot to firmware (UEFI)
4. Set the POST time to 5 seconds
5. Disable RAID in `System configuration`
6. Set "UEFI Boot Path Security" to `Never`
7. Disable secure boot (or we get an `Initramfs unpacking failed` error).
8. Apply the changes
9. Enter the boot menu (with F12)
10. Select the USB drive.

The message "starting kubuntu" appears for a short time, then we get the error posted above.

I don't understand the meaning of the error.

How can we proceed to install Kubuntu? Do we have to change more settings in the BIOS? Update something? Wait for the next Kubuntu release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved our issue by updating the BIOS. The initial version was "1.1.1". We updated to "1.2.1".

The error message still appears for a brief moment (so it's just a warning in fact) but we get the screen allowing to chose to try or install Kubuntu. In order to start the live USB session ("try kubuntu"), we have to select "Start Kubuntu (Safe Graphics)" at the very start of the boot.

Unfortunately, it seems that we can't install the system at the moment because this model does not allow to switch the SATA operations to "AHCI". It prevents Linux from seeing the hard drive. There's a Dell thread about this issue : https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Not-able-to-set-SATA-operation-to-AHCI-in-BIOS-Inspiron-7490/td-p/7393794